# If the sentence "What are the contents of that box" is correct how, then, is the sentence "What is the demographics of that area" also correct?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement

1. What are the contents of that box? ... correct
2. What is the demographics of that area? ... incorrect
3. The demographics for that area are ___. ... correct

Why do I keep reading sentences in the newspaper where the word 'are' is being replaced by the word 'is' in plural situations as in sentence #2? If the sentence, "What are the contents of that box" is correct, how, then, is the sentence, "What is the demographics of that area" also correct? I thought I understood the singular default?
One would not say, "Demographics of that particular area is" - 'are' would be correct in both of the last two sentences, right?
I'm afraid that Journalism, Grammar, Spelling, and Editing are all dead? Very little punctuation is used anymore and sometimes I don't understand what I'm reading without it. I stay confused. it's just sad with the amount of misspelling always and the proofreading that happens very seldom.
Thanks so much.

Comment: I did find a few examples of this online, but you should edit some into your question for context.

Comment: Oxford defines _demographics_ as _statistical data relating to the population and particular groups within it._ It's grammatically plural, but could be seen as uncountable or even, as an academic subject, singular (like _physics, mathematics_), which is presumably why some writers feel justified in using a singular verb.

Answer (score 1):

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/demographics) lists two senses:

> **demographics**
>
> ■ [*noun*] [*plural*]:  the number and characteristics of people who live in a particular area or form a particular group,
> especially in relation to their age, how much money they have and what
> they spend it on:
>
> - *The demographics of the country have changed dramatically in recent years.*
> - *No one has exact demographics on (= information about the quantity and characteristics of the people who live in) the area.*
>
> ■ [*noun*]
> [*non-count*]: the study of people and society in a particular area or
> particular group, typically used in marketing to decide which products
> to sell there and how to advertise those products successfully:
>
> - *Companies use demographics to compile a 'customer profile' of their target audience*

Thus, plural-only (I'd not say count) and non-count usages are available for *demographics*. And as with *physics* or *mathematics*, *demographics* takes singular verb agreement in this second (the study of, and the general field of study) sense:

- *Demographics is the study of people and society in a particular area or
  particular group ....*

However, in the second example given above, the first sense is used, and plural agreement would be correct. As correctly appears in the third example.